# python string replacement with % character/**kwargs weirdness

Tags: python, string-formatting

Following code:

```
def __init__(self, url, **kwargs):
    for key in kwargs.keys():
        url = url.replace('%%s%' % key, str(kwargs[key]))
```

Throws the following exception:

```
File "/home/wells/py-mlb/lib/fetcher.py", line 25, in __init__
url = url.replace('%%s%' % key, str(kwargs[key]))
ValueError: incomplete format
```

The string has a format like:

```
http://www.blah.com?id=%PLAYER_ID%
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You probably want the format string `%%%s%%` instead of `%%s%`.

Two consecutive `%` signs are interpreted as a literal `%`, so in your version, you have a literal `%`, a literal `s`, and then a lone `%`, which is expecting a format specifier after it.  You need to double up each literal `%` to not be interpreted as a format string, so you want `%%%s%%`: literal `%`, `%s` for string, literal `%`.

Comment: Ah yes! Close, but %%%s%% is what I wanted: so it's a percent, followed by the actual key in kwargs, followed by a percent. But now that I look at %%%s%% in my code, it looks really annoying and I'm wondering if there's a nice way of doing what I am trying to do.

Comment: The nicer way is: url.replace('%'+key+'%', str(kwargs[key]))

Answer (score 3):

you need to double the percentage sign to escape it:

```
>>> '%%%s%%' % 'PLAYER_ID'
'%PLAYER_ID%'
```

also when iterating over the dictionary you could unpack values in the for statement like this:

```
def __init__(self, url, **kwargs):
    for key, value in kwargs.items():
        url = url.replace('%%%s%%' % key, str(value))
```

Comment: In general, Python 2.x code should default to using `iteritems` over `items`; the latter generates a list in memory while the former returns a generator that iterates the map.  It won't make a difference here really, but it's good to have the right habit.

Besides that, looks good.

Comment: huh? where do you see indications of the py2k code? it's py3k, and there no `iteritems` in existence.

Answer (score 1):

Adam almost had it right.  Change your code to:

```
def __init__(self, url, **kwargs):
    for key in kwargs.keys():
        url = url.replace('%%%s%%' % key, str(kwargs[key]))
```

When key is FOO, then `'%%%s%%' % key` results in `'%FOO%'`, and your url.replace will do what you want.  In a format string, two percents results in a percent in the output.